# django-filter how to style RangeFilter?

Tags: python, html, css, django

I have a problem with styling a range input.
I'm using django_filters.RangeFilter class on declaring my filter:
`parent__length = django_filters.RangeFilter(label="Length")`

It looks like this as follows:

[image]

I want to have this length input in one row separated with the "-" sign.
I'm using the bootstrap grid when I'm displaying that filters.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just dealt with this same issue when trying to render the RangeFilter using django-crispy-forms and I did not find a great solution. I ended up modifying the template directly by making my own widget that extends django_filters.widgets.RangeWidget.

```
class MyRangeWidget(django_filters.widgets.RangeWidget):
    template_name = "my_range_widget.html"
```

The default template from django_filters/widgets/multiwidget.html looks like the following and you can modify it with any html you want.

```
{% for widget in widget.subwidgets %}{% include widget.template_name %}{% if forloop.first %}-{% endif %}{% endfor %}
```

Then you can use it in your filter like this.

```
parent__length = django_filters.RangeFilter(label="Length", widget=MyRangeWidget)
```

Comment: Thanks. Im using this code to make it work:
```<div style="display:table">
{% for widget in widget.subwidgets %}
    <div style="display:table-cell">
    {% include widget.template_name %}
    </div>
        {% if forloop.first %}
            <div style="display:tabel-cell">-</div>
        {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</div>```